# CSS Shapes for Carousel Indicators that are Responsive Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

So, im making a project that is half personal and half for my exam. I have the entire infrastructure done, styling done, everything is almost done but i still have one thing that i would like to learn to implement it, this being: **CSS Shapes for Carousel Indicators that are Responsive**.

Now,
We all know how Bootstrap 3 Carousels are, we know that they have some additions to display Indicators for where the slider is standing an active position and the arrows to navigate between them.
The only thing that i never used before are CSS/3 Shapes and im just getting upset that i never tried to do something like this (wich i reckon is quite an easy thing to do).

So yeah, i kinda went on a Rage Quit rampage and deleted that entire code piece for the carousel (I tried but i kinda give up and decided to dropped, chill a bit and try again.. didn't work as you might notice.)

Enough of chit chat, im working with this Carousel
[image: My carousel (Graphic View)]

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="../images/0044-new.jpg">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="../images/0033-new.jpg">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="../images/0045-new.jpg">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, what im trying to achieve is this kinda of look whitout the need of Images (More a fan of having all in a CSS file if possible.)
**Have in mind that this is a Fan Site, not trying to copy. Just trying to make it feel a bit more like it (I do have my own style though.)**
[image]

My question would be: What's the best way to approach this to solve it while keeping the responsiveness? Because i now it certainly has to do with Viewports Breakpoints but to be honest i have no single idea of how they work entirely (Still can't understand it but im working on reading the docs in my freetime)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you can make circles by using border radius. I would probably make the carousel button section background with a block and two css triangles as pseudo elements (:before and :after).

See the fiddle I've made here: http://jsfiddle.net/andyfurniss/yb1x7zso/

```css
ul {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin:0 20px;
    font-size:0;
    background:#111;
}

ul:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
    top:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:30px solid #111;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
}

ul:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:-20px;
    top:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:30px solid #111;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
}

li.current {
    background:red;
}

li + li {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

With regards to responsiveness, I'd just use media queries to adjust the size of the 'discs' and the 'disc' container.

Media queries let you specify styles for a certain resolution or resolution range which is how bootstrap works. I'm not sure exactly where you'll need to change things in bootstrap because I don't really use it as I like to work from the ground up with my styling but have a look at this for a bit of an explanation: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/.